# PHP login form not working, says incorrect credentials all the time no matter what i enter

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have attempted to put a login page on to my web page that i am developing as a learnig curve. I am almost there i think, i have created a table in my database that stores the username and passwords and i have a php script that i have wrote that should check the database and if the credentials are correct then let me though to the webpage. However no matter what i enter in the username and password box it says incorrect. This is the php code:

```html
<?php session_start();
     
    $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "Dylanc";
 $password = "xxxx";
 $dbname = "FirstAttempt";
 
 // Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
       
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['Username']) . "' and Password = '" . mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['Password'])) . "'");
     
    $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    
    if ($row['admin']==1) {
    $_SESSION['usersession'] = $_POST['Username'];
    header("Location: mainpage.php");
    exit;
 }

    } elseif ($row['admin']==0) {
    header("Location: index.php?error=2");
    exit;
     
    }
     
    header("Location: index.php?error=1");
    exit;
    
?>
```

I have a row in my table called admin, on the accounts that should be able to login this is set to 1 so the code should check the username and password and if the admin row is set to 1 then go thorugh to "mainpage". If admin is set to 0 this should fail and set error =2. I then have this included in the index page:

```html
<?php if($_GET['error'] == '2'): ?>
    Login Credentials are Incorrect<?php endif ?><?php if($_GET['LogOff'] == '1'): ?>Logout Successful<?php endif ?></h3>
            </caption>
            <form action="Credentials.php" method="post" name="login">
            <tr>
                <td class="menu" style="width: 394px">&nbsp;Username: </td>
                <td class="menu" style="width: 204px">
                <input class="auto-style16" name="username" style="width: 250px" type="text" size="20" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="menu" style="width: 394px">&nbsp;Password:&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="menu" style="width: 204px">
                <input class="auto-style16" name="password" style="width: 250px" type="password" size="20" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="menu" style="width: 394px; height: 23px;">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="auto-style1" style="height: 23px; width: 204px;">
                <input class="auto-style16" name="Submit1" type="submit" value="Login" style="height: 28px" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="menu" colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
```

So if the error=2 then dispaly incorrect credentials. I am getting that error each time so it is like the php code runs and think the admin row is set to 0 even though it isn't. Hope this makes sense. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Try to var_dump your $_POST and $row to see what you're getting, please do expand upon your question to share your results.

Comment: if this is a new site, why on earth are you using the mysql_* DB libraries? They were deprecated years ago, and are removed entirely in PHP 7. They haven't been updated for a long time and contain security vulnerabilities. Also the way you've written your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection - learn what happened to little Bobby Tables: http://bobby-tables.com/ . Switch to the PDO or mysqli_* libraries and learn to use prepared statements. I can only assume you used some ancient tutorial to help you build this - find a newer one with more credibility.

Comment: Lastly, whilst hashing your passwords gets a +1, MD5 is trivial to crack with modern processors, so consider using a stronger algorithm

Comment: and I suspect one reason it's not working is because PHP array indexes are case sensitive - so `$_POST['Password']` != `$_POST['password']`. Your HTML form has the `name` attributes in lower case, so use `$_POST['password']` to access the password variable. Check all your other fields too.

Comment: And again...actually I've just noticed, unless it's a typo, that you're creating a new connection (`$conn`) using object-oriented mysql**i** but then making the query using standard mysql_query, I'm surprised this is not chucking errors all over the place. It needs a total rewrite.